# Rutas internas de laravel no funciona (Internal Server Error / Error 500)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Acabo de montar un proyecto ya existente en Laravel. Está configurado a través de un virtualHost con XAMPP.

El tema es que solamente funciona el home:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'local.proyecto.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'VacantesController@home');
    Route::get('/test', 'UserController@test');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/vacantes-de-trabajo', 'VacantesController@vacantes');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/vacantes-de-trabajo/busqueda={q}', 'VacantesController@vacantes');
    Route::post('/vacantes-de-trabajo/busqueda', 'VacantesController@busqueda');
    Route::get('/vacantes-de-trabajo/trabajos-de-{categoria}-en-{estado}', 'VacantesController@vacantesCategoriaEstado');
    Route::get('/vacantes-de-trabajo/trabajos-de-{categoria}-en-{estado}/busqueda={q?}', 'VacantesController@vacantesCategoriaEstado');
    Route::get('/vacantes-de-trabajo/trabajos-de-{categoria}', 'VacantesController@vacantesCategoria');
    Route::get('/vacantes-de-trabajo/trabajos-en-{estado}', 'VacantesController@vacantesEstado');
    Route::get('/vacantes-de-trabajo/oferta-de-trabajo/{id}', 'VacantesController@detalle');
    Route::get('/vacantes-de-empresa/oferta-de-trabajo/{id}', 'EmpresasController@detalle');
    Route::get('/blog', 'BlogController@home');
    Route::get('/blog/{slug}', 'BlogController@post');
    Route::get('/postular/{id}', function(){
        return redirect ('http://candidato.proyecto.com');
    });
});
```

Al querer consultar cualquier pagina/sección interna, me devuelve:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

He hecho pruebas con rutas simples como:

```
Route::get('/nosotros', function () {
    return ´Hello nosotros´;
});
```

pero no funciona.

## ¿A que se deberá?

### Características del proyecto

```
"php": ">=5.5.9",
"laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
```

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.15 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2015 12:40:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: has probado a sacar las urls del Route::group?
Te recomienod instalar el paquete https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer para que asi te de un poco mas de informacion sobre el error, puedes acceder a los logs con tu urldeproyecto/logs, por que lo normal seria que te diera otro tipo de error, pero ese es bastante inusual, si puedes compartir lo que te de el Log, aloemjor podemos ayudarte un poco mas

Comment: He implementado el laravel-log-viewer pero al intentar cargarlo, por ejemplo: "local.app.com/log" me da el mismo error por ser una url interna. Es decir, el mismo problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví, el problema lo tenía con el archivo .htaccess en la configuración de las friendly urls:

#### Anterior

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|ipad|ipod|android|nokia|ios|opera m(ob|in)i|iemobile|symbian|samsung|sec-|htc|huawei|ericsson|sonyericsson|blackberry|motorola|sagem|kyocera|zte|kddi|docomo|j-phone|kwc|lenovo|lg|mot|softbank|nec|audiovox|alcatel|sharp|sie-|sanyo|sendo|amoi|xda|bird|benq|palm|pantech|panasonic|fly|asus-|baiduispider|googlebot-mobile|nintendo|psp|dalvik|windows ce|foma|brew|webos|fennec|netfront|teleca|obigo|vodafone|up.browser|portalmmm" [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^$ mobile_index.html
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^$ index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|ipad|ipod|android|nokia|ios|opera m(ob|in)i|iemobile|symbian|samsung|sec-|htc|huawei|ericsson|sonyericsson|blackberry|motorola|sagem|kyocera|zte|kddi|docomo|j-phone|kwc|lenovo|lg|mot|softbank|nec|audiovox|alcatel|sharp|sie-|sanyo|sendo|amoi|xda|bird|benq|palm|pantech|panasonic|fly|asus-|baiduispider|googlebot-mobile|nintendo|psp|dalvik|windows ce|foma|brew|webos|fennec|netfront|teleca|obigo|vodafone|up.browser|portalmmm" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).* mobile_$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).* $1.html
```

#### Ajuste

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On  ---->>> NO TENÍA ESTA LÍNEA ACTIVADA
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|ipad|ipod|android|nokia|ios|opera m(ob|in)i|iemobile|symbian|samsung|sec-|htc|huawei|ericsson|sonyericsson|blackberry|motorola|sagem|kyocera|zte|kddi|docomo|j-phone|kwc|lenovo|lg|mot|softbank|nec|audiovox|alcatel|sharp|sie-|sanyo|sendo|amoi|xda|bird|benq|palm|pantech|panasonic|fly|asus-|baiduispider|googlebot-mobile|nintendo|psp|dalvik|windows ce|foma|brew|webos|fennec|netfront|teleca|obigo|vodafone|up.browser|portalmmm" [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^$ mobile_index.html
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^$ index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|ipad|ipod|android|nokia|ios|opera m(ob|in)i|iemobile|symbian|samsung|sec-|htc|huawei|ericsson|sonyericsson|blackberry|motorola|sagem|kyocera|zte|kddi|docomo|j-phone|kwc|lenovo|lg|mot|softbank|nec|audiovox|alcatel|sharp|sie-|sanyo|sendo|amoi|xda|bird|benq|palm|pantech|panasonic|fly|asus-|baiduispider|googlebot-mobile|nintendo|psp|dalvik|windows ce|foma|brew|webos|fennec|netfront|teleca|obigo|vodafone|up.browser|portalmmm" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).* mobile_$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
***RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]***  ---->>> EL AJUSTE ANTERIOR NO FUNCIONABA
```

Comment: Están comentadas las líneas con ***

Comment: Gracias por la retro!